# How to have a Fixed Length for xsl:text?

Tags: xml, xslt

I am creating a fixed width CSV File using XSLT. I have headers within thee file and I have created them as below:

```
 <xsl:template match="wd:Report_Data">
 <xsl:text>"Group Number","User ID","Social Security     Number","Employee ID","Relation","First Name","Middle Initial",Last Name","Employee Status","Hire Date","Termination Date","Termination Reason","Job Title","Salary","Hourly Rate","Hours Per Week","Benefits Base Salary","Compensation Date","Date of Birth","Gender","Home Address Line 1","Home Address Line 2","City","State","Postal Code","Country","Work Email","User Name","Time Type","Worker Type","Company"</xsl:text>
<xsl:for-each select="wd:Report_Entry">
```

In the output CSV File, Headers are not aligned properly. How do we align thee headers with Fixed Length?

Example: Group Number (20 extra spaces), User ID(10 extra spaces), etc

Thanks

Comment: Which version of xslt are you using ? And what is your desired output ?

Comment: @Vebbie My XSLT version is 1.0 and my desired output is fixed width CSV file. Thanks

Comment: Could you please edit your question to show a sample of your XML, and the output you actually expect? Thank you!

Comment: Please state also which XSLT 1.0 processor you will be using (there are some EXSLT extension functions that could be really useful here, if your processor supports them).